# Как вложить if в print Python?

Tags: python, переменные

Есть булевая переменная. Мне нужно проверить ее значение и в зависимости от этого изменить аргументы, передаваемые в print

```
amusingsize = True
print ("Amusing size: %s") %(if(amusingsize) "GB" else "MB")
```

Как можно сделать подобное? Я не хочу городить лишних блоков if/else.

Comment: print ("OK" if True else "NO!") пойдет?

Comment: У вас ужасный стиль кода.

Не пишите так, это не добавляет понимание того, что вы хотите получить.

Comment: `print "Amusing size: " . (amusingsize ? "GB" : "MB")` но у вас Python, так что страдайте без удобных тернарных Си-подобных операторов )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
amusingsize = True
print ("Amusing size: %s" %("GB" if amusingsize else "MB"))
```

Comment: А мой вариант почему не заработал? Что я не так сделал?

Comment: Ну синтаксис у питона такой - как попало писать нельзя )

Comment: Я что то не могу понять, почему если MB у меня стоят как True, то печатает GB и наоборот.

Comment: "GB" if amusingsize else "MB"
Эквивалентно:
    if amusingsize:
        print("GB")
    else:
        print("MB")

Answer (score 10):

Вот еще такой "хакерский" вариант

```
print "Amusing size: %s" % ("MB", "GB")[amusingsize]
```

Comment: Это можно использовать, только если хорошо известно, что выражение (amusingsize в данном случае) возвращает `False`, `True` `0`, `1`, т.е. `"+-"[n < 0]` -- кратко и понятно, но в общем случае многие переменные, которые используются с `if`, сами не являются булевыми. Более близким эквивалентом для `a if x else b` будет `[b, a][bool(x)]`.

Answer (score 5):

На самом деле все просто:
для однострочников с условиями есть строго определенные правила (оно одно) и выглядит в вольном переводе так:

```
"значения для True" IF statement ELSE "значения для False"
```

Но в то же время каждый такой однострочник может являться значением для True/False в другом однострочнике. Например, вот такой нечитаемый кусок кода:

```
['FizzBuzz' if i%3+i%5==0 else 'Fizz' if i%3==0 else 'Buzz' if i%5==0 else i for i in xrange(1, 16)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
amusingsize = True
print ("Amusing size: %s") %("GB" if amusingsize else "MB")
```